# Spammers are being nastier withing the second!

Tags: discussion, review, spam-handling

To the reviewers that check First Time posts, please, be very alert about this new kind of attack:

Spammers are now posting seemly valid answers/questions ripping of other posts/answers inside/outside AU.

Clear example: **the answers were deleted as spam, maybe a >10K rep user could take the screenshots**

https://askubuntu.com/a/336799/169736 and https://discussions.apple.com/message/22109175#22109175

Another:

https://askubuntu.com/a/336796/169736 ripoff https://askubuntu.com/a/128471/169736

https://askubuntu.com/a/290431/169736 was ripped of here https://askubuntu.com/a/336801/169736

[image]

[image]

If you check the edit logs, you will see that I deleted some links, before discovering the pattern. **I know I shouldn't edit spam, but at first I didn't think this.** Be extra precarious with answers/questions that has links, check where they are heading, and flag it if you feel that is spam.

Moderators will know how to deal with this, and if it's necessary to bring this topic to other sites.

Comment: FYI: spam posts should **not** be edited: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110030/should-spam-posts-be-edited

Comment: @Takkat I wasn't sure it was spam until I noticed the pattern. I was just seeing a kind of "signature". Afterwards I came back and flagged them as spam.

Comment: Yeah it's always an issue with those links... I commented for others who may come here too.

Comment: I wonder what would happen if first posts containing urls were automatically sent for moderation prior to being accepted.

Comment: @vasa1 for that is the "First post" review queue :(

Comment: Aren't first posts in the review queue **already** accessible to everyone including any search engine bots around at the time?

Comment: @vasa1 if you mean that they appear in the Review queue inmediatly, yeah, I think is right.

Comment: Extra precarious?