# Here I go again

Tags: discussion, tags

Ok I have gotten a few `possible duplicate question` tags already tonight. I just want to say that I do **"NOT"** feel we should have to re-word our questions 100 different ways just to see if there is a  answer to them.

Again question in question → [Does Ubuntu Terminal run in the background?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/350645/does-ubuntu-terminal-run-in-the-background)

Now someone thinks it is a duplicate of this → **Running programs in the background from terminal**

Ok I see how that might answer my question but when you type Does Ubuntu run in the background, in the title box, that suggestion does not come up.

So I have to re-word my question every possible way before I post just so I don't get tagged? Come on Guys & Gals, there has to be a better way...

Comment: Think you are making a big fuzz about down-votes (some are automatically given by the system) and close as a duplicate. If you want to dispute a duplicate the only thing you need to do is flag it so a moderator can review it for you, nothing else.

Comment: @BrunoPereira Thank you for the information. It may seem like a big fuss but the Point of the matter is still true. I did not know about flagging it for the mods so again thanks for that info.

Comment: This is now beating a dead horse, but the point of the matter is irrelevant.  By making a fuss about a downvote, you detract from the community itself by making a huge fuss over something that is basically not important.  I get downvotes and closed items or possible duplicate close votes sometimes, but it's irrational to complain about it.  But as Bruno said, if you want to dispute a duplicate, flag it, or edit your post and explain why it's not a duplicate. (editing the post and explaining puts it in the reopen votes queue apparently)

Comment: @BrunoPereira by now the Community don't downvotes dupes. http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/190947/213575

Comment: @Braiam ... I did not say community down-votes dupes. C'mon, is this kinder garden time or something? I said that he is making a fuzz about: a) down-votes that can or not be given automatically by the system; b) closed questions he had that were closed as duplicates of another. Is this more clear to you will you or do I need to break it down a little bit more so you can understand? I can go down to children’s level and break it down more for you, just let me know if you need that.

Comment: And I'm only saying that Community don't downvote duplicates, which was the only downvotes that the system ever made @BrunoPereira . I'm commenting your *"about down-votes (some are automatically given by the system)"* which by now is not true. System (Community) doesn't downvote any question ever.

Comment: @Braiam wow, this is getting tiring: *which was the only downvotes that the system ever made (...)*, not true; *System (Community) doesn't downvote any question ever.*, this is only true after the 5th of August.

Comment: @BrunoPereira could you read [this comment](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/7218/spammers-are-being-nastier-withing-the-second#comment11418_7218) and apply it to what my first statement tried to convey? BTW, "ever" has 3 connotations/meanings: 1) Always 2) At any time 3) In any form/way. Hint: I'm using the third.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well in this case it was me who voted to mark your question as a duplicate of the nicely and thouroughly answered [question on how to detach a terminal process](https://askubuntu.com/questions/106351/running-programs-in-the-background-from-terminal). The reasons I had were the following:

- Once you see the terminal it does not run in the background.
- It is not the terminal you want to run in the background, it is the applications you need to detach.
- To make this clear we would have to edit your question, which then would immediately have made it a 100% dupe of the question I linked to.
- The dupe has very good answers which I believed will help you to solve your issue.

Still, having your question around (i.e. not delete it) is a good idea. It will help people with the same issue who will eventually find your question earlier than the other one, depending on search terms used. They then will immediately be directed to a good question with helpful answers. This is the essence of our site: get questions answered quickly and thouroughly.

The answer you have by now will only tell you that the terminal application will terminate when you close the window (which is not really a surprise). This does not really help much in case we want to learn how to detach a process. Rather than adding this as another answer to your question I felt it was a better idea to direct you to the best question & answer we have on that topic.

Hope you understand my reasoning.

Comment: Very well said Takkat. I do understand your reasoning now and I accept it. But actually it in reality the terminal terminating when you close it is not a surprise to you. But to me or a new to Linux person it is new. I would bet almost anything that if you remembered back you could remember a time when you didn't know the terminal would terminate. Sometimes we forget that new people honestly do not know these answer "YET". Again, Thank you for your explanation. I truly will see it differently now!

Comment: @SoCalDiegoRob: I believe the combination we have now is great. We have the fact answered that the terminal really closes when we close it, and we will immediately have people directed to the solution.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks again for your explanation. It helped tremendously to understand why it was happening...