# SPAM attacks again!

Tags: discussion, spam-handling

Today we found a clever way spammer are trying to prevent falling into the spam protection system... that is recommending software relevant to the question so people in their curiosity search what is that about so they get ads revenue. Beware, any tool recommendation too vague. An example of such spam:

[image]

BTW, it doesn't help that then you provide the link of the SPAM (*winks @EricCarvalho*).

**The [Spammers are being nastier withing the second!](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/7218/spammers-are-being-nastier-withing-the-second)**

Comment: "clever" is a big word and worst than supplying a link to the "tool" was using a canned comment to ask the users to explain why his crappy spam post would be an answer to the question, and still fail to flag the post itself...

Comment: @BrunoPereira well, is clever, 4 people managed the post and only 1 saw a pattern... I say that's clever.

Comment: Pretty Clever i would say!

Comment: @BrunoPereira: When I come across posts where I can leave a comment like MadMike did, I generally leave a comment and don't flag such posts. Should I flag them for deletion? (I don't flag them since the user might edit the post after being deleted but might not flag it again for undeletion).

Comment: @Aditya In its current form, it is not an answer so flag it! (leaving a comment would also be good)

Comment: I recommended one of those answers for deletion, since it's a "link-only" ish answer. Or too little information...

Comment: And I thought it was just another poor non-native-english speaking soul,  unable to translate his guidance in proper form, craving for some rep. I feel so abuse :(... ;)

Comment: @Seth actually is SPAM, not NAA but pure SPAM... the thing only works in Windows... and SU says it got spammed too by it.